# Updating FB SDK to latest version not working

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdk

I have a legacy app that used the old version of **FBSDK**, and every time I logged in to FB developer dashboard I see this warning:

> Your Facebook SDK for iOS is out of date and missing important iOS 11
>   fixes that make it easier for people to log into your app. Upgrade Now

I have done updated my FB SDK to v4.40.0 using cocoapods (confirmed this by NSLog `[FBSDKSettings sdkVersion]`). But what confusing me now is the warning still there even though SDK was successfully updated.

FB gave instruction to update:

> To make your app compatible with iOS 11, use the latest Facebook SDKs
>   for iOS. If you link to the SDKs with CocoaPods, you must update your
>   pods for the SDKs your app uses and recompile your app. You can also
>   download the latest version of the Facebook iOS SDK, integrate it into
>   your app, and recompile.

What I've done so far is :
• Update SDK using cocoapods ✅
• Recompile app ✅

Does anyone know that is the real reason why the warning doesn't disappear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add screenshot of issue... As of my thought this is not iOS related issue...

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution to this issue? Did the warning eventually disappear? I'm having this issue too. I updated the SDK version via cocoa pods, log SDK version - everything good - but Facebook dashboard still says my SDK is out of date.

Comment: yeah same for me have done the steps but still shows sdk is out of date? are you guys using react native or native IOS?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old query but still if someone stumbles upon it, here are a few things you may consider.

a)Facebook needs to receive an app event in order to reflect the update on the dashboard. Try to trigger an event. For example, launch the app.

b)Check if you're initialising the SDK properly.
In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` add `ApplicationDelegate.shared.initializeSDK()`.

c)Since Apple is strictly monitoring user consent for App Tracking, add `FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled` & `FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled` to info.plist and set appropriate boolean values respectively.

Recommended way is to set the same as `false`, ask the user for consent and on approval, set the values to `true`. Use the following code for the same.

```
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
      ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
          Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true
          Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true
        case .denied:
          Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = false
          Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false
        default:
          Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = false
          Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false
        }
      }
}
```

d) Sometimes, the minimum deployment target of your application could be preventing the SDK to update to latest version. To confirm if that's the case, set the pod to latest version in podfile as following:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~>15.0.0'
```

update the pods using `pod update` or `pod install`
If the minimum deployment target is hindering the update, you'll receive an error like this:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKCoreKit":
  In Podfile:
    FBSDKCoreKit (~> 15.0.0)

Specs satisfying the `FBSDKCoreKit (~> 15.0.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

If this occurs, try changing the minimum deployment target of your app. Also ensure that the platform in your podfile is also set to the new and higher minimum deployment target such as `platform :ios, '12.0'`.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you @the-pedestrian for the note about the `platform :ios, '12.0'. Could you please tell me where you found this info? I had previously 11.0 set and caused a build failure, but I couldn't find after searching where which FB SDK version needs which iOS minimum version. Is this info from Facebook? Or from Apple? A link would be very appreciated.

Comment: In my case, I had used a trial and error approach using point d. I’d check and share if there’s any info available for the minimum deployment version via Facebook

Comment: Phase 2 (initiation) was a complete lifesaver! Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Thanks @MakwanBarzan